# Android Alarm every day several times a day

Tags: android

I want to create an alarm which would go off every day at predefined hours. Do I need to create a PendingIntent for every hour and add it to the AlarmManager, or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I set alarm like this using pending intent

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set "
            + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);

}
```